# VB.NET Sendmessage/postmessage problems

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, sendmessage, postmessage

I have a form, inside that form I have a panel.

Clicking on button 1, I start a new process of IE and I set IE.mainhandle as my panel.handle, so I have IE inside my panel.

Now I want to sent a mouse click on IE.  How can I do?

I've just tried with Sendmessage and Postmessage, but it doesen't work!

```
 Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal Hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As UInteger, ByVal lParam As UInteger) As UInteger

 Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal Hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As UInteger, ByVal lParam As UInteger) As UInteger

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        Dim pnt = New Point(430, 290)
        Dim x As Integer = 430
        Dim y As Integer = 290

        Dim p As Process = Process.GetProcessById(processID)
        SetActiveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle)

        PostMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, MakeLParam(x, y))
        PostMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MakeLParam(x, y))

        SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, MakeLong(x, y))
        SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MakeLong(x, y))

    End Sub

Private Shared Function MakeLParam(ByVal LoWord As Integer, ByVal HiWord As Integer) As IntPtr
        Return New IntPtr((HiWord And &H10000) Or (LoWord And &HFFFF))
    End Function

 Public Function MakeLong(ByVal loWord As Integer, ByVal hiWord As Integer) As Integer

        Return (hiWord - 1 << 16) Or (loWord + &HFFFF)

    End Function
```

Can someone help me please?